# Why Isn't MySQL Blob Recommended

Tags: mysql, database, blob

I'm thinking of putting together a little magazine which I want to show online, and thought that a good way of doing it would be to have a table consisting of an ID number, plus blob data to show each page as an image.

So if I had an issue consisting of 10 page, it would look like:

```
ID . Page_1_Blob . Page_2_Blob . Page_3_Blob . Page_4_Blob . Page_5_Blob . etc
```

Thing is that I've seen a lot of negativity when it comes to storing blob data for images, more specifically due to the fact that it slows down your database? How true is this? And are there any arguments in favour of using blob data in this way?

Comment: Is there a good reason to serve just a picture of each page of the magazine instead of a link to a proper HTML document? Do you destroy the previous issue each time you write a new one?

Comment: Maybe "Magazine" is the wrong word. It's more like a brochure where people can view it online as a page-by-page booklet, and then download the actual file as a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

So my understanding of it is that the BLOB gets stored within the actual database file. So if you had a 10GB magazine, then the 10GB would end up in the actual SQL database file. The file gets loaded in to the RAM when you make a query. Obviously searching through a 10MB file is much faster than loading and searching through a 10GB file. The answer to this is to use a SqlFilestream to store information in the actual file structure of the server, however this causes all kinds of ballaches because the SqlFilestream API only works on the actual machine, not a remote one. For my database I have had to set up a WCF program to add huge files to my database.

If you only have a database of say 10 pages, then by all means stick in in a BLOB, however if you are adding magazine after magazine then it will cause slowdown.

If you try to do queries like "select * from magazines", then these queries take forever because it actually returns the binary data from there server as part of the query. If you run that kind of query on a video, then you'll be waiting a long time.

Comment: I can't find any documentation suggesting that MySql has the SqlFilestream type.

Comment: Sorry I thought you were using Microsoft SQL. The title was a bit misleading. At present I think you are stuck with BLOB then.

Comment: Well to be honest I would probably be selecting `page_2_blob FROM magazines WHERE id = X`, as each magazine page would be hosted on its own web page, i.e. `website.com/issues.php?issue=1&page=2`. I just wan't sure how selecting a BLOB from a large database could be much different from selecting a large TEXT article.

Comment: It is all about size. A BLOB could be 100GB+, whereas you could never have a block of text of that size. If your BLOB is 1MB total then it wont affect your database at all. The problems appear when people go nuts and start putting huge amounts of info in, which is what some people will do.

Comment: @ChristopherVickers Do you know of any way to calculate the size of a BLOB based on an image? As it suggests, each page is going to be the size of a peice of paper - More than likely A5.

Comment: Well the BLOB is the actual image. BLOB is Binary Large Object. Work out how many pages and how big each are and thats how big your database will become. A BLOB field is literally just a column in your database for storing binary data that the server probably wont know what to do with, unlike text, integers etc. Images come in different qualities, different dimensions. Unfortunately, I cant really help you with that bit.

Comment: Personally, what I would do is not store the data in the database. It creates all kinds of hassle, instead just have the PHP server return the files form the server file structure.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm thinking of doing, as I'm probably not going to know how many pages each issue is going to be anyway. Cheers Chris